# Unindentified inequality from Hardy-Littlewood-Polya

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality

I found this while trying to understand a theorem. Could anyone tell me which famous inequality is being mentioned here, and where I can find a proof/ statement of that inequality? The article refers to the famous book Inequalities by Hardy-Littlewood-Polya, but, I could not understand which particular inequality is being mentioned.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps [Karamata's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality) is what you are looking for; it is essentially the additive analogue of the inequality in the excerpt you provide. Here's another reference: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?highlight=majorization+karamata&t=14975

It is also called the Hardy-Littlewood inequality, which might explain the reference to Hardy and Littlewood.